# Python XML ElementTree - findall

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm working with XML files.
My file is like that :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<root>
    <query label="nom1" code="1234">
        <where a="1" b="2">
            <condition id="1534" expr="expression1"/>
        </where>
    </query>
    <query label="nom2" code="2345">
        <where a="2" b="3">
            <condition id="6784" expr="expression2"/>
        </where>
    </query>
</root>
'''

myroot = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

I want to have the label and the expr for each query.
For example, it will print me :

```
query 1 :
    nom1
    expression1
query 2:
    nom2
    expression2
```

Do you know how can I do that ?
I know how to print all the label:

```
for type_tag in myroot.findall('root/query'):
    print(type_tag.attrib['label'])
```

And how to print all the expr:

```
for e in myroot.findall("root/query/.//*[@expr]"):
        print(e.attrib['expr'])
```

But I don't know how to do for both in the same time.

Any comment will be helpful !

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findall()` to search relative to the respective element:

```
for i, type_tag in enumerate(myroot.findall('./query')):
    print(f'query {i+1}:')
    print(type_tag.attrib['label'])
    for e in type_tag.findall('./where/condition'):
        print(e.attrib['expr'])

# query 1:
# nom1
# expression1
# query 2:
# nom2
# expression2
```

### Explanations:

- `myroot.findall('./query')` will get you all `<query>` elements beginning to search from the root node
- `type_tag.findall('./where/condition')` will get you all `<condition>` elements within the current query `tpye_tag`